# How to insert data into Hibernate managed Bridge table or Join table?

Tags: java, hibernate

As there is no POJO class associated with Bridge table when It is Hibernate managed Bridge table. How to insert Data into it.

You can consider the Scenario Many Students has Many Courses.

How to store data into student_course table when we update students or courses table.

Following piece of code is for understanding purpose and tested the results

```
    Student student = new Student();
    student.setName("abc");
    List<Course> courses = new ArrayList<Course>();
    Course course1 = new Course();
    course1.setName("course1");
    Course course2 = new Course();
    course2.setName("course2");
    Course course3 = new Course();
    course3.setName("course3");
    courses.add(course1);
    courses.add(course2);
    courses.add(course3);
    student.setCourses(courses);
    session.save(student);
    session.close();
```

The above piece of code is only inserting the data in both the tables. 
But there is no indication that course1, course2 and course3 belongs to student as It is not saving the data in student_course table.

Comment: any specific use case you are doing that?

Comment: Yeah. I need for one of the applications I am developing. Till now, I used to create a user defined class for accommodating other variables in the Bridge class. Now I dont need any extra variables. So I want to know how to insert data through this approach?

Answer (score 1):

A bridge/join/cross table is either represented by a many-to-many relationship, or by a separate entity which represents the relation.

Many-to-many example:

```
Person
    List<Club> clubs;

Club
    List<Person> members;

cross table person_club (person_id, club_id);
```

Here clubs and members are in a many-to-many relationship, mapped to a cross table. If you add a member to a club or a club to a person, data is added to the cross table when the entity is saved.

Entity example:

```
Article

User

Tag
    String label;

ArticleUserTag
    Article article;
    User user;
    Tag tag;

cross table article_user_tag (article_id, user_id, tag_id)
```

Here ArticleUserTag is an entity representing the relationship between articles, users and tags. To tag an article, a new ArticleUserTag instance must be created with the desired article, user and tag. When it is saved, data is inserted into the cross table.

EDIT: don't set a new List on the Student. Try this:

Student class:

```
public class Student {

   private List<Course> courses;

   @ManyToOne(....)
   public List<Course> getCourses() {
       return courses;
   }
}
```

Somewhere in your code:

```
try {
    Student student = new Student();
    student.setName("abc");
    session.save(student);   

    Course course1 = new Course();
    course1.setName("course1");
    session.save(course1);  

    Course course2 = new Course();
    student.setName("abc");
    session.save(course2);  

    student.getCourses().add(course1);
    student.getCourses().add(course2);
    session.save(student);         
}
finally {
    // always close in finally block, or use Java 8's try-with-resources
    session.close(); 
}
```

Comment: Please provide the answer with appropriate syntax because I am able to save the data of both tables but It is not affecting the bridge table. Please find the updated question

Comment: You must save the Course instances first.

Comment: It didn't help Adriaan Koster. No change in the results.